# How can I optimize this LINQ statement for speed?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, optimization

The following LINQ statement finds items with duplicate values for a particular property, groups them by count then does another grouping to get a boolean back.

I'm just curious how this can be improved, it seems a bit wasteful and as this is part of a object model validation library I'd quite like to get it as speedy as I can.

Speed of execution is a priority, but any other suggestions are welcome.

```
var grouped = from g2 in
                 (from i in item.ParentList
                  where _filter(i)
                  group i by propGetter(i) into g
                  select new { Count = g.Count(), Items = g })
              group g2 by g2.Count == 1 into g3
              select new { IsUnique = g3.Key, Items = g3 };

foreach (var g in grouped)
{
    foreach (var grp in g.Items)
    {
        foreach (var itm in grp.Items)
        {
            if (g.IsUnique == false)
                itm.AddPropertyError(_propertyName, (int)Validations.Unique, _message);
            else
                itm.RemovePropertyError(_propertyName, (int)Validations.Unique);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of improvement did you have in mind?

Comment: What is the performance hit you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry, have edited the question to add more info. I'm not really experiencing any noticeable performance hit, it just looks (to me) a bit wasteful. I'm no LINQ guru by any means.

Comment: @Marlon why optimize something that doesn't give you any trouble?

Comment: I'm always up for learning something - I just thought the query doesn't look like its using LINQ to the best of its abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oskar said, you probably don't want to optimize the query for speed unless profiling shows that it's causing a problem. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). If you want to optimize the query for readability, here is one way to simplify the second part:

```
var items = grouped
    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)

foreach (var item in items)
{
    ...
}
```

Edit regarding your comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that you were referencing `g.IsUnique` inside the innermost loop. Here is one way to resolve that problem without 3 levels of indentation, but it may not be the best way:

```
var uniqueItems = grouped
    .Where(group => group.IsUnique)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)

var nonUniqueItems = grouped
    .Where(group => !group.IsUnique)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Items)

foreach (var item in uniqueItems)
{
    ...
}

foreach (var item in nonUniqueItems)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is the way to go, optimize for readability. Three levels of nesting is generally hard to read and to modify.

Comment: Can I still get the boolean key from that?